# Por qué al realizar un registro por axios no lo realiza FireFox y chrome si?

Tags: laravel, axios

tengo el siguiente problema y no se a que se deba. Actualmente estoy trabajando con ventanas modales, y para realizar el registo utilizo Axios,pero cuando realizo el registro en el navegador chrome no me sale ningun error, pero cuando lo trato de hacer en firefox me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error de mapa de fuente: request failed with status 404
URL del recurso: http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js 
URL del mapa de fuente: axios.map[Saber más]

Error de mapa de fuente: request failed with status 404
URL del recurso: http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/axios.js 
URL del mapa de fuente: axios.map[Saber más]

Error de mapa de fuente: request failed with status 404
URL del recurso: http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css 
URL del mapa de fuente: bootstrap.css.map[Saber más]
```

Al parecer no me redirecciona al error sino me manda a esta pagina:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Source_map_errors

La verdad no se que esta ocurriendo. Les dejo mi codigo de axios para registrar:

```
 nuevaLocalidad:function(){
                 const params ={
                   nombre:this.vue.nombreLocalidad,
                   idMunicipio:this.vue.selectMunicipio
                 }
                 if(this.vue.nombreLocalidad.length !== 0  && this.vue.selectMunicipio !== '0'){
                   axios.post('gestion-localidades',params).then((response)=>{
                        this.vue.nombreLocalidad = '';
                        this.vue.selectMunicipio = '0';
                    });
                    $('#createLocalidad').modal('hide');
                 }
               },
```

En mi controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $localidad = new Localidad();
        $localidad->nombre = $request->nombre;
        $localidad->Municipio_id = $request->idMunicipio;
        $localidad->estatus =  1;
        $localidad->save()
}
```

Comment: Prueba quitando las funciones con flechas por un `function()`

Comment: En que parte tengo que quitar la flecha?